# Hadoop streaming falling with python

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to run a Map-Reduce job on Hadoop Streaming with Python scripts, and It work fines when I use jupyter terminal.

But when I run the following

```
./bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.7.jar -file /usr/local/hadoop/python/assignmap1.py /usr/local/hadoop/python/assignreduce1.py -mapper "python assignmap1.py" -reducer "python assignreduce1.py" -input input1/data.txt -output output
```

It come up this error map and reduce are both 0%

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

here is my code of map

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

def map():
    dataset = pd.read_table(sys.stdin)
    for a in range(len(dataset)):
        key = dataset.loc[a][0]
        date = dataset.loc[a][1]
        value = dataset.loc[a][3]
        
        #return(mapped)
        print(" ".join([key,date,value]))
        
    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    map()
```

and here are code of my reuce

import sys
import pandas as pd

```
def reduce():
    temperature = {"City":["Date","Temp",""]}
    for data in sys.stdin:
        splited = data.split(" ")
        key = splited[0].strip()
        date = splited[1].strip()
        tem = splited[2].strip()
        temp = int(tem[0:2])
        abstemp = abs(25 - temp)
        
        if temperature.get(key) == None:
            temperature.update({key:[date,temp,abstemp]})
        else:
            temp_last = temperature.get(key)[2]
            if temp_last > abstemp:
                temperature.update({key:[date,temp,abstemp]})
        
    for key in temperature:
        print(" ".join([key,str(temperature.get(key)[0]),str(temperature.get(key)[1])]))
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    reduce()
```

I have no idea what is the problem and the hadoop configuration should be right because I am using docker that should be well setted.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple things that may be wrong her, first try to give python path below as first line in both reducer and mapper

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

For example, in mapper

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pandas as pd

def map():
    dataset = pd.read_table(sys.stdin)
    for a in range(len(dataset)):
        key = dataset.loc[a][0]
        date = dataset.loc[a][1]
        value = dataset.loc[a][3]
        
        #return(mapped)
        print(" ".join([key,date,value]))
        
    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    map()
```

Next, you just need to give scipt name for mapper and reducer like below

```
-mapper  assignmap1.py -reducer  assignreduce1.py
```